# Gmail API/PUB SUB send 2 messages when new email is received

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to trigger a Google cloud function every time an email arrives to the mailbox.

I have configured the pub sub subscription with the Google Cloud Function with "PUSH" Delivery Type.

I have also configure Gmail account to send notifications to my Cloud Pub/Sub topic,

```
request = {
  'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
  'labelFilterAction': 'include,
  'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/mytopic'
}
gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

The problem is that I receive 2 pub sub messages in the same milisecond every time a new email arrives:

[image]

I have tried changing the `labelFilterAction` and `labelIds` but nothing change. I always receive 2 messages.

Any explanation about why 2 messages and how to avoid them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had some success by enabling Exactly Once delivery on the Pub/Sub subscription

Answer (score 0):

You have made a watch request in INBOX label,
you might be receiving notification when a message is received in the inbox and the second maybe when the message is read or moved.

also make sure you are not making multiple watch requests

The watch method (which subscribes to notifications regarding a user’s inbox) is supposed to be idempotent. While that’s broadly the case, if you send multiple watch requests simultaneously, you end up with multiple subscriptions, meaning every event for that user gets pushed to your endpoint multiple times!

make sure to stop the previous watch request or if you are saving the watch response, the watch response includes an expiration time use that to make the next watch request